# Document custom Framework XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks

I'm actually creating a framework for iOS / OSX and i would like to document my public methods as apple does.

For instance, assume that i have the method `doSomething:` ...
i would like to receive the description *"Do something very interesting!"* in the autocompletion pane of XCode.

This is an example of the desired result:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add comments with a specific syntax in your code, it will be converted into documentation.

Read this article on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/).

Answer (score 3):

You can add *doc comments* in the method declaration:

```
/**
 * Summary of the method.
 *
 * @param firstParam This affects what the method does.
 * @param secondParam And so does this!
 *
 * @return Something very interesting.
 */
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html).